# how to load every second number into registers using the instruction LODSB

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a code where I find the sum of 10 numbers from the `numbers` table. How can I find the correct sum of every other number? Do you need to somehow work with `lodsb` to load `eax` every second number into EAX? Or do you still need to do something with the add instruction?

```
    cld

    mov esi, OFFSET numbers ; in `numbers` i have 10 numbers
    mov edi, esi
    
    mov ecx, 10
    myLoop:
    push ecx
        lodsb ; here i add each digit in turn to the `eax` register
        add sum, eax ; here i summarize the numbers
    pop ecx
    loop myLoop
    
    mov eax, sum
```

Comment: To skip every other number, add `inc esi` before or after `lodsb`, depending on whether you want to skip the very first. Oh, and then you need to reduce the count, too, of course, else your pointer will run off the end.

Comment: Or you could forget about `lodsb` and simply do `add eax, [numbers+8*ecx]` while counting up with `ecx` from 0 to 4 (inclusive).

Comment: `lodsb` only merges a byte into the low 8 bits of EAX; it doesn't zero-extend.  Did you maybe want `lodsd`?  `lodsq` on x86-64 would load a pair of bytes and increment the pointer by 8.  Of course the appropriate loop trip-count would be half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a code where I find the sum of 10 numbers from the `numbers` table.

### An array of bytes

Assuming your code is correct for summing these 10 numbers, the only thing missing is zeroing the `EAX` register beforehand. That's not something that `LODSB` is going to do!

```
  mov  esi, OFFSET numbers
  mov  ecx, 10
  xor  eax, eax
myLoop:
  lodsb
  add  sum, eax
  loop myLoop
  mov  eax, sum
```

Only summing every second **byte**

```
  mov  esi, OFFSET numbers
  mov  ecx, 10 / 2 ; Half
  xor  eax, eax
myLoop:
  inc  esi         ; Skip (or use an extra LODSB here)
  lodsb
  add  sum, eax
  dec  ecx
  jnz  myLoop
  mov  eax, sum
```

### An array of dwords

The `LODSB` instruction does not load the whole number. Use `LODSD`.

```
  mov  esi, OFFSET numbers
  mov  ecx, 10
myLoop:
  lodsd
  add  sum, eax
  loop myLoop
  mov  eax, sum
```

Only summing every second **dword**

```
  mov  esi, OFFSET numbers
  mov  ecx, 10 / 2 ; Half
myLoop:
  add  esi, 4      ; Skip (or use an extra LODSD here)
  lodsd
  add  sum, eax
  dec  ecx
  jnz  myLoop
  mov  eax, sum
```

Similar to what @Jester suggested.

```
  mov  ecx, (10 / 2) - 1
myLoop:
  add  eax, [numbers + ecx * 8 + 4]
  dec  ecx
  jns  myLoop
```